# Auto Conversion of floating point number to int. - Java

Tags: java, int

I was writing a program and forgot to write `Math.round()` and when I was reviewing the code I saw this

```
int number = 1/2;
```

why doesn't this raise an error of
`required type: int | provided:double`?

Note: If this is a silly question please forgive I new to programming.

Comment: This just results in integer division. The two arguments (numbers) are treated as ints. The result will be zero as integer division truncates whatever is after the decimal point (i.e., it'll round down to the nearest integer).

Answer (score 1):

its an **automatic** type conversion.

Here the variable 'number' stores the auto converted value to int 0.

well auto type casting doesn't always work.
when you write `int number = 0.5;` it will give an error

but when you write `int number = (int) 0.5;` its called an **explicit type casting** and now number stores 0 value.

Comment: Actually there's no automatic type conversion in this particular example. Both operands (provided to the division operator) are plain `int`s, thus the operator will perform integer division.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken I am actually confused. is it casting to int or something else.

Comment: @BluNyte there is *no* (automatic) type conversion in your particular example since both operands provided to the division operator are treated by the compiler as `int`s. The division operator is defined both for `int`s and `double`s (and the other integer and floating point types). When the division operator is supplied with two `int`s, it'll perform integer division (in this case on `int`s), and the return type of this is also an an integer (in this case an `int`).

Answer (score 1):

Normally doing math operations using `double` will most likely be giving `double` on the other hand for int it will give a `int`.

However, if thats not the case Java will strip the number after the dot (.) and set the value to whatever is left. Example:

```
3/4 = 1.5 => Java => 1
```